# Resetting a form with computed oneWay properties in Ember

Tags: javascript, forms, ember.js, binding

I'm modelling a form embedded inside a modal and I'd like it to be reset when my route calls reset explicitly in the controller. This is somehow the form Im managing inside a modal:

```
{{#modal-window title='Size management' close='removeModal'}}
  <label>
    <span>Size</span>
    {{input value=width class='width'}}
    <span>X</span>
    {{input value=height class='height'}}
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Left</span>
    {{input value=left class='left'}}
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Top</span>
    {{input value=top class='top'}}
  </label>
{{/modal-window}}
```

This is the controller that presents/manages the form:

```
App.SizeEditorModalController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  width: Ember.computed.oneWay 'model.width'
  height: Ember.computed.oneWay 'model.height'
  top: Ember.computed.oneWay 'model.top'
  left: Ember.computed.oneWay 'model.left'

  reset: ->
    # I'd like to restore the oneWay properties to its default values coming from the bound model
```

This is the route that shows the modal resetting previously the controller involved.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  actions:
    showModal: (name, model)->
      controller = @controllerFor name
      controller.reset()
      @render name,
        into:   'application'
        outlet: 'modal'
        model:  model
    removeModal: ->
      @disconnectOutlet
        outlet:     'modal'
        parentView: 'application'
```

When I set some values to the form controls, they stay there forever, because I'm using oneWay properties and I don't know if exists any way of resetting those properties to get the values from the source binding again.
I don't want the model to be updated before clicking 'Save' button.
This is a quite common situation and I'm sure Ember has an easy way of achieving this, but, at the moment I cannot see what is this way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick

```
App.register 'controller:size-editor-modal', App.SizeEditorModalController, { singleton: false }
```

If I add this, my controller is not singleton anymore and then a new instance is created each time the modal requires it. Then the controller uses the computed properties with its default values coming from the model.
I supposed that `render` (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_render) method would behave in this way when passing a model like `render` (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_render) helper does, but it has nothing to do.
Im still missing the case when I'd like my controller computed oneWay properties to be reset without the need of having to create a new instance of the controller, though.

Comment: A good alternative is to use components instead of controllers. That will also ease the transition to Ember 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Use The rollback function of the model.
If a model is dirty you can rollback it like:

````
/**
If the model `isDirty` this function will discard any unsaved
changes
Example
```javascript
record.get('name'); // 'Untitled Document'
record.set('name', 'Doc 1');
record.get('name'); // 'Doc 1'
record.rollback();
record.get('name'); // 'Untitled Document'
```
@method rollback
*/
````

Every unsaved changes will be gone.

Comment: Im not using ember data. I would have to implement something alike. Anyway, what if I move to another place in the app? Those changes would stay there if I dont call rollback explicitly. Even worst, observes would execute its logic in other places even if they are not definitive changes.